# NSAttributedStringKey.font not working

Tags: cocoa

I want to add temporary attributes to the text in an NSTextView. It is working for `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` but not for `NSAttributedStringKey.font`. It's also unfortunate that I can't get to the definitive headers to see where `NSAttributedStringKey` is defined. (I tried cmd-clicking but it's a dead end without the actual definitions).

The code below should work but the font doesn't change

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: NSTextView!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        textView.layoutManager?.delegate = self
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: NSLayoutManagerDelegate {
    func layoutManager(_ layoutManager: NSLayoutManager,
                       shouldUseTemporaryAttributes attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [:],
                       forDrawingToScreen toScreen: Bool,
                       atCharacterIndex charIndex: Int,
                       effectiveRange effectiveCharRange: NSRangePointer?) -> [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?
    {
        var attributes = attrs
        if let font = NSFont(name: "Comic Sans MS", size: 14) {
            attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = font
        }
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation of `addTemporaryAttributes`: "Currently the only temporary attributes recognized are those that do not affect layout (colors, underlines, and so on).".

Comment: oh, thanks a lot, I missed that. I guess I have to work around that then.